# Como trago registros do banco de dados ao clicar no checkbox utilizando jquery e ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Bom, consigo trazer dados do banco utilizando ajax, mas quero que ao clicar no **input** do tipo **checkbox**, ele realize a consulta ao banco e me mostre os dados dentro de um flexbox. Possuo 10 checkbox, com nomes diferentes e carregaram dados diferentes, e ao clicar no checkbox *'regua'*, ele realize a consulta no banco e me traga na tela tudo que for *regua* (carregando todo tipo de régua em cada um dos flexbox).
No entanto os dados vem no ajax, e também consigo puxar no jquery, mas quero que venha logo após o *checked*, criei o codigo já verificando o checked de cada input mas depois disso não sei como realizar a consulta ao banco nesse mesmo código, por isso coloquei os *alert* para ver se funciona.

**CONCLUSÃO:**

- Quero ao CLICAR o checkbox, fazer uma consulta ao BD, e  me trazer aquela informação, dentro do flexbox.

**HTML**

`<div id="conteudo">`
`<div class="flex">REGUAS:</div>`
`</div>`

```
<div class="checkboxes">

                        <input type="checkbox" id="regua" onclick="checkFiltros()" name="check">
                        <label for="regua">Régua</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="motor" onclick="checkFiltros()" name="check">
                        <label for="motor">Motor</label> <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="canal" onclick="checkFiltros()" name="check">
                        <label for="canal">Canal</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="fase" onclick="checkFiltros()" name="check">
                        <label for="fases">Fase</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="vigencia" onclick="checkFiltros()" name="check">
                        <label for="vigencia">Vigência</label>

                    </div>
```

**Jquery**

````
                        $("#regua").click(function(e) {  
                        if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
                              alert("O alerta está funcionando.");
                        }); 


                   )};

                    $("#motor").click(function(e) {
                        if($(this).prop("checked") === true) {

                            alert("O alerta está funcionando.");
                        }
                    });

                     $("#canal").click(function(e) {
                        if($(this).prop("checked") === true) {

                            alert("O alerta está funcionando.");
                        }
                    });   

                    $("#fase").click(function(e) {
                        if($(this).prop("checked") === true) {

                            alert("O alerta está funcionando.");
                        }
                    });   

                    $("#vigencia").click(function(e) {
                        if($(this).prop("checked") === true) {

                            alert("O alerta está funcionando.");
                        }
                    });

        </script>```
````

**PHP**

```
<?php
include("./php/conect_postgre.php");

  $consulta_bd = "SELECT * FROM uniao";
  $result=pg_query($conexao, $consulta_bd);
  if  (($result)){
      while($linha_usuario = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo $linha_usuario['regua'] . "<br>";
      }
  }else{
      echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma função para o AJAX e envie como parâmetro a informação vinda de um checkbox checado.

Por exemplo, o AJAX está dentro da função `checkFiltros()`, ficaria assim:

```
function checkFiltros(dado){
   AJAX AQUI
}
```

E no evento click, você pode pegar todos os checkboxes de uma vez em vez de criar um *event handler* para cada um:

```
$(".checkboxes :checkbox").click(function(){
   // envia o id para a função se o checkbox estiver checado
   if(this.checked) checkFiltros(this.id);
});
```

O seletor `".checkboxes :checkbox"` irá pegar todos os checkboxes dentro da div com a classe `.checkboxes`.

Na função `checkFiltros(dado)`, o valor do argumento `dado` será o id do checkbox marcado, aí basta você enviar esse valor no seu AJAX, por exemplo:

```
function checkFiltros(dado){
    $.ajax({
       url: "pagina.php",
       method: "post",
       data: { buscar: dado},
       ...resto do código
    });
}
```

Em relação a jogar o resultado da consulta dentro de uma div (como você já diz estar recebendo os dados via AJAX), basicamente seria usar o `.html()` do jQuery (semelhante ao `.innerHTML`) no retorno da requisição:

```
success: function(data){
   $("#conteudo .flex").html(data);
}
```

Comment: Agradeço! Funcionou!

Comment: Mexi em algo e deu erro novamente.

```<script>
                 $(".checkboxes :checkbox").click(function(){  
                        // envia o id para a função se o checkbox estiver checado
                        if(this.checked) retornConsult(this.id);  
                        
                     });
                </script>```

Comment: ```<script>
                    function retornConsult(){
                        
                         $.ajax({
                            url: "home_.php",
                            method: "post",
                            data: { buscar: id},
                            
                         }); 
                          success: function(data){
                         $("#conteudo .flex").html(data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            </script>```

Comment: Esqueci de falar, mas tem que tirar o onclick de todos os checkbox

Comment: tirei, mas quando clico, não me retorna os dados do BD

Comment: Esse Ajax que vc mostrou aí está errado.

Comment: o que está errado?     
```
<script>
                    function checkFiltros(dado){

                         $.ajax({
                            url: "home_.php",
                            method: "post",
                            data:{ 
                           buscar: dado,
                            
                         }); 
                     }
                          success: function(data){   
                         $(".container").html(data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            </script>```

Comment: O `success` tem que estar dentro do `$.ajax({});`

Comment: Está correto agora???
<script>
                    function checkFiltros(dado){

                         $.ajax({
                            url: "home_.php",
                            method: "post",
                            data:{ 
                           buscar: checkbox,
                            
                         success: function(data){
                            $("#conteudo .flex").html(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
             });

Comment: Ainda está errado.. É assim: `function checkFiltros(dado){
   $.ajax({
      url: "home_.php",
      method: "post",
      data:{ buscar: dado},
      success: function(data){
         $("#conteudo .flex").html(data);
      }
   });
}`

Comment: ESSE SCRIPT TA CERTO???
<script>
                 $(".checkboxes :checkbox").click(function(){
                        // envia o id para a função se o checkbox estiver checado
                        if(this.checked) checkFiltros(this.id);
                    });
            </script>

Comment: Tá certinho....